# Editing Paragraph tag with a default style values

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress to run my website, but recently I noticed something strange with my single.php. I found that all my p tags has a default style:

```
<p style="font-size: 12px;line-height: 150%;"></p>
```

I want to style my font-size paragraph but its work only with !important value. So, How I could change this default style? I want to remove it form p tag. I searched my functions.php but I found nothing.... maybe its a default value form WordPress core files?

I know I could remove it with jquery or style it with css but the ideal solution would be to remove that extra code ""font-size: 12px;line-height: 150%;"" I really dont need it!

I saw that other wordpress theme have also a default value for p tag so it may be wordpress!!! But How I could find it and change it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: if it's only affecting the one file, just do a search in the stylesheet containing that rule. I don't see what the big deal is really. *"How I could find it"* - Search `*.css` containing "x". *"Done like dinner"* ;-)

Comment: do you mean it is hardcoded in single.php, or at least did you check that?

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand me; the p tag has inline css, it is not styled with the stylesheet. @RST no it isnt in single php .... the only thing that is in single php is <?php the_content ?> .... I searched my function php to see if there is something about that the_content ...but i found nothing

Comment: So...um... remove it perhaps? If it's not part of the stylesheet, then it's in your .php file.

Comment: @Fred He may be asking if it is OK to remove it. He may be new to the whole experience and not want to mess anything up.

Comment: @Jeff.Clark I honestly don't know where to throw myself here *lol* If so, then sure... he should just remove it.

Comment: I don't know how without jquery.... if I remove it with jquery I will add extra code to my single php code; I will use this method lastly if I found no answer.

Comment: @CristianManolache To be honest, I don't know what your question is about, sorry. I'll have to let someone else try and figure out exactly what your question is about, good luck.

Comment: @christian Is there anything keeping you from removing the inline CSS? That is quite an easy solution. If you want to, replace it with a class and do what you need to in your css file.

Comment: I told you, with brute force, I don't know how!!! This is the code responsible for my post content <?php the_content(); ?> .. So I searched my single.php, style css and function php but I found nowhere anything about that values.... So Could I do it with php?

Comment: It seems it is just in one file, this means it is in the source of the file. You should be able to check that when you open the post and switch to 'text' mode tab (top right of the editor area)

Answer (score 0):

Solved... I found the code responsible for those css values.... Thanks you all for your replays... hope the best for all of you!!!